# Gerstanharber bracket and derived Hom

Tags: homological-algebra, derived-categories, hochschild-cohomology

Let $A$ be a honest algebra or more generally, a DG algebra. It is known that the Hochschild cochain complex is quasi-isomorphic to the derived Hom complex, i.e. one has 
$$\mathrm{HH}^{\bullet}(A,\,A)\,\cong\,\mathrm{H}_{-\bullet}[\mathrm{RHom}_{A^e}(A,\,A)]\,.$$
Moreover, there is a Gerstanharber bracket structure on $\mathrm{HH}^{\bullet}(A,\,A)$.

My question is that by the isomorphism above, can we construct this bracket from the derived Hom complex? Or is the Gerstanharber bracket related to some operations in the derived category of $A^e$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is in "[An exact sequence interpretation of the Lie bracket in Hochschild cohomology](http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/schwede/Ext-Crelle.pdf)" (Stefan Schwede, J. reine angew. Math. **498** (1998), 153--172)